# error in SD card program

Tags: c, sd-card

i run sd card program in linux but i found following error....but i include header file also

```
anish@ubuntu:~/Desktop/testing/sd card$ gcc -o sdcard sdcard.c
/usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.4.3/../../../../lib/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x18): undefined reference to `main'
/tmp/ccVMCgzn.o: In function `SDCardInit':
sdcard.c:(.text+0x23): undefined reference to `SPI1Byte'
sdcard.c:(.text+0x4d): undefined reference to `SPI1Send'
sdcard.c:(.text+0x8b): undefined reference to `SPI1Byte'
sdcard.c:(.text+0xb2): undefined reference to `SPI1Send'
sdcard.c:(.text+0xfd): undefined reference to `SPI1Byte'
sdcard.c:(.text+0x102): undefined reference to `CRC16Bit_GenTable'
/tmp/ccVMCgzn.o: In function `SDResponseMatch':
sdcard.c:(.text+0x128): undefined reference to `SPI1Byte'
/tmp/ccVMCgzn.o: In function `SDResponseDontMatch':
sdcard.c:(.text+0x162): undefined reference to `SPI1Byte'
/tmp/ccVMCgzn.o: In function `SDWriteBlock':
sdcard.c:(.text+0x1db): undefined reference to `CRC_7Bit'
sdcard.c:(.text+0x202): undefined reference to `SPI1Send'
sdcard.c:(.text+0x23b): undefined reference to `CRC_16Bit'
sdcard.c:(.text+0x24a): undefined reference to `SPI1Byte'
sdcard.c:(.text+0x25d): undefined reference to `SPI1Send'
sdcard.c:(.text+0x26b): undefined reference to `SPI1Byte'
sdcard.c:(.text+0x27b): undefined reference to `SPI1Byte'
sdcard.c:(.text+0x287): undefined reference to `SPI1Byte'
sdcard.c:(.text+0x2f7): undefined reference to `SPI1Byte'
/tmp/ccVMCgzn.o: In function `SDReadBlockPart':
sdcard.c:(.text+0x35e): undefined reference to `CRC_7Bit'
sdcard.c:(.text+0x388): undefined reference to `SPI1Send'
sdcard.c:(.text+0x3f0): undefined reference to `SPI1Byte'
sdcard.c:(.text+0x3ff): undefined reference to `CRC_16Bit_AddByte'
sdcard.c:(.text+0x41c): undefined reference to `SPI1Byte'
sdcard.c:(.text+0x43b): undefined reference to `CRC_16Bit_AddByte'
sdcard.c:(.text+0x463): undefined reference to `SPI1Byte'
sdcard.c:(.text+0x472): undefined reference to `CRC_16Bit_AddByte'
sdcard.c:(.text+0x48e): undefined reference to `SPI1Byte'
sdcard.c:(.text+0x4a0): undefined reference to `SPI1Byte'
sdcard.c:(.text+0x4d6): undefined reference to `SPI1Byte'
/tmp/ccVMCgzn.o: In function `SDWriteBlockHead':
sdcard.c:(.text+0x53c): undefined reference to `CRC_7Bit'
sdcard.c:(.text+0x563): undefined reference to `SPI1Send'
sdcard.c:(.text+0x59b): undefined reference to `CRC_16Bit'
s    dcard.c:(.text+0x5aa): undefined reference to `SPI1Byte'
sdcard.c:(.text+0x5ca): undefined reference to `SPI1Byte'
sdcard.c:(.text+0x5f0): undefined reference to `CRC_16Bit_AddByte'
sdcard.c:(.text+0x5ff): undefined reference to `SPI1Byte'
sdcard.c:(.text+0x616): undefined reference to `SPI1Byte'
sdcard.c:(.text+0x626): undefined reference to `SPI1Byte'
sdcard.c:(.text+0x632): undefined reference to `SPI1Byte'
sdcard.c:(.text+0x6a2): undefined reference to `SPI1Byte'
/tmp/ccVMCgzn.o: In function `SDWriteMultiBlock':
sdcard.c:(.text+0x702): undefined reference to `CRC_7Bit'
sdcard.c:(.text+0x729): undefined reference to `SPI1Send'
sdcard.c:(.text+0x76e): undefined reference to `CRC_16Bit'
sdcard.c:(.text+0x77d): undefined reference to `SPI1Byte'
sdcard.c:(.text+0x790): undefined reference to `SPI1Send'
sdcard.c:(.text+0x7a5): undefined reference to `SPI1Byte'
sdcard.c:(.text+0x7b5): undefined reference to `SPI1Byte'
sdcard.c:(.text+0x7c1): undefined reference to `SPI1Byte'
sdcard.c:(.text+0x7fa): undefined reference to `SPI1Byte'
sdcard.c:(.text+0x847): undefined reference to `SPI1Byte'
```

Comment: You need to link with the library that contains `SPI1Byte` etc

Comment: Is this an embedded device/microcontroller?

Comment: its an embedded device for settop box

Answer (score 1):

Looks like to me your forgot to link a couple of libraries.

or if you want to generate an object file to link it afterwards, this would be better

```
gcc -o sdcard.o sdcard.c
```

Comment: I don't know what kind of project your are working on but you might try to take a look at `makefiles`

Answer (score 1):

**crt1.o *is the C Runtime***. It specifies where to start the program and few other things. Execution starts at **_start** symbol and then jumps to the main defined in the program. So from error

```
In function `_start':
(.text+0x18): undefined reference to `main'
```

my guess is that you may have misspelled your main function, may be you have named it Main or something else.

For other errors, you will need to link with the library that provides these functions or, if you are using functions in other source files, you will need to compile them too then link all of these files together.